# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I tried to install python-opencv using pip, but the terminal throws an error every time:

Command Issued:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Traceback:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I'm using the latest version of pip. Also, I am not a sudo user, so I can't install it via the GitHub Repo.
How do I install opencv-python?

My python version is **3.7.6**.
My Linux version is **CentOS 7**

Comment: what is your Python version?

Comment: In order for us to help you, you'll need to tell us what version Python you are using and provide the exact command that you tried to use.

Comment: The last version of opencv-python (v4.1.2.30) is released for Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 => 3.8 for many OS (Linux, Mac and Windows): https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files

Comment: The Python version is 3.7.6

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual output if there is no corresponding wheel for the target OS you are currently using. I have encountered this particular error when I tried to install `python-opencv` on Alpine Linux. The problem is that Alpine is not supported by `manylinux` as it is not a GNU/Linux distro. This [Github issue](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/75) describes the problem and a possible workaround, but I suggest to use a Debian based distro instead.

Comment: I have the "CentOS Linux" on my machine

Comment: You can then use this guide: https://dotlayer.com/how-to-install-and-configure-opencv-on-centos-7-for-python/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but I do not have sudo access.

Comment: I think CentOs is GNU libc, so you could try forcing the installation of the manylinux package by following this: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3969#issuecomment-247381915

Comment: I added the file to **/lib/python3.7 but still it won't install opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

That happend to me too. That was because a weak internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can type these commands below to update and upgrade your opencv version:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python

pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).